# Changing "required" property of a field in SharePoint 2010 custom Newform.aspx

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have created a custom newform.aspx by cloning the form generated by SharePoint Designer and added it to a VS2010 project. Everything seems to be working fine like setting the value etc... but I couldn't figure out how to set the `Required` property of a field.

Based on a certain condition I would like to set the required property of a field to true or false.

I am accessing the controls using `CompositeField` and `BaseFieldControl` but they dont seem to give a handle to set required property value.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution by grabbing the property as below instead of getting to the control.

```
objListFormWebPart.ItemContext.Fields["fieldDisplayName"].Required = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `AllowBlank` property of inner Items (for e.g. `TextField`'s) of `CompositeField` to true/false.